# awk match two files, and read with delimiter '_' in the second file in reverse order

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have to find the common lines in file1 and file2. 
In this code this counts the delimiter from starting. 
I want to read the lines in file2 with delimiter '`_`' in the reverse order
(last to first).

```bash
awk -F'_' '
    FNR==NR {a[$1,$2,$3,$4]; next}
    ($11,$12,$13,$14) in a {print $0}
' file1 file2
```

file1

```
01Aug2020_10_48_25
06Jun2020_01_11_02
21Jun2020_09_30_07
05Jul2020_21_53_41
27Aug2020_21_15_15
17Aug2020_18_56_49
10Jun2020_07_00_25
10Jun2020_15_24_20
26Jun2020_09_25_34
30Jul2020_07_17_04
27Jul2020_03_36_35
24Jul2020_18_05_34
```

file2

```
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01_January_2020/01_Jan/re_01Jan2020_11_58_40_B2_W1_x_90.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/08_August_2020/01_Aug/ESC_re_01Aug2020_10_48_25_B3_W1_x_270.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_11_58_40_B4_W1_x_180.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_11_58_40_B5_W1_x_0.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01_January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_07_36_B1_W1_x_0.00_Oz_0.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/06June_2020/21_Jun/ESC_re_21Jun2020_09_30_07_B2_W1_x_90.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01_January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_07_36_B3_W1_x_270.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01_January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_07_36_B4_W1_x_180.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_07_36_B5_W1_x_0.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01_January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_19_13_B1_W1_x_0.00_Oz_0.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01_January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_19_13_B2_W1_x_90.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_19_13_B3_W1_x_270.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_19_13_B4_W1_x_180.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01_January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_19_13_B5_W1_x_0.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01_January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_30_50_B1_W1_x_0.00_Oz_0.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/01_January_2020/01_Jan/ESC_re_01Jan2020_12_30_50_B2_W1_x_90.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/07July_2020/27_Jul/ESC_re_27Jul2020_03_36_35_B3_W1_x_270.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
```

Comment: Please try harder to explain your question more clearly.  (1) It would help a lot if you showed expected output.  (2) It would also help if you simplified the example data.  It looks like *every* line in `file2` begins with ``/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/``.  Could you replace that with `A_K_K/`?  It seems like that wouldn’t really change the question, and it would make the file easier to read.  You could probably also remove all occurrences of “`2020`”, `ESC_`” and  “`0.00.mmts`”.  (3) What does “this counts the delimiter from starting” mean? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) What does “I want to read the lines in file2 with delimiter '`_`' ***in the reverse order (last to first)***” mean?  (5) Why are you looking at `$11`, `$12`, `$13` and  `$14`?  (6) Do you realize that your `file2` does not have the same number of fields on every line? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Shooting in the dark: what keeps you from using

```
grep -ffile1 file2
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/08_August_2020/01_Aug/ESC_re_01Aug2020_10_48_25_B3_W1_x_270.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/06June_2020/21_Jun/ESC_re_21Jun2020_09_30_07_B2_W1_x_90.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/07July_2020/27_Jul/ESC_re_27Jul2020_03_36_35_B3_W1_x_270.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
```

, given the data structure in `file1` is as unique as shown in your example and matches only the desired target substrings in file2?

Comment: Ah; if only we knew whether this is what the OP wants.

Comment: or perhaps, to meet OP's condition on parsing file 2 in reverse order: `grep -f file1 < <(tac file2)` ?

Comment: @Cbhihe I read the "in reverse order" thing as if they wanted to address the fields from the end of each line (because the lines contain a varying number of `_` at the start, but not if counting from the end).

Comment: @kusalananda: Ah, yes I guess that could be as you say. I understood differently.

Answer (score 0):

Since the directory pathnames in the second file contain a varying number of underscore characters (e.g. `01January_2020` vs. `01_January_2020`), you can't use `_` as the delimiter for that file, at least not while assuming that the data you want to compare are in the same fields on all lines. You also have *filenames* with a varying number of underscores (e.g. `re_01Jan2020_11_58_40_B2_W1_x_90.00_Oz_10.00.mmts` and `ESC_re_01Aug2020_10_48_25_B3_W1_x_270.00_Oz_10.00.mmts`) which makes this even more obvious.

Assuming the number of `_` does not vary *after* the date string, you may instead address the fields from the end of each line if you wish (this may be what you refer to when saying "in reverse order"), and I'll show this at the end of this answer. My initial approach would be to trim the data so that we get the date string separated from the rest of the line.

We do this by first chopping off the directory pathname, i.e. the start of the string up to the last `/`.  We do this to avoid accidentally matching the date in parent directory names.  We assume the date string is the first substring that starts with a digit and ends before `_` followed by a non-digit.

```bash
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$0]; next }
    {
        datestamp = $0
        sub(".*/[^0-9]*", "", datestamp)
        sub("_[^0-9].*", "", datestamp)
    }

    (datestamp in a)' file1 file2
```

The output of this, given the data in the question, is

```
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/08_August_2020/01_Aug/ESC_re_01Aug2020_10_48_25_B3_W1_x_270.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/06June_2020/21_Jun/ESC_re_21Jun2020_09_30_07_B2_W1_x_90.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
/media/AGH/AGH_K_K/academi/P2020/07July_2020/27_Jul/ESC_re_27Jul2020_03_36_35_B3_W1_x_270.00_Oz_10.00.mmts
```

---

Addressing the fields from the end of each line can be done by using `NF`, the internal variable that holds the number of fields in the current record:

```bash
awk -F _ 'NR == FNR { a[$1,$2,$3,$4]; next }
    ($(NF-9) SUBSEP $(NF-8) SUBSEP $(NF-7) SUBSEP $(NF-6) in a)' file1 file2
```

Note the use of `SUBSEP` above.  This is a special separator that `awk` uses to when creating the combined index key into an associative array. Since we are creating a string that we want to check the existence of in the index of `a`, we need to explicitly use `SUBSEP` to delimit the different parts of the combined index key.

The result is the same as with the first solution in this answer.